# How to make an Image file to be automatically downloadable when an html form is submitted?

Tags: html, download, submit

How to do make a file downloadable when the html form is submitted?

```
<form id="form" name="form" action="" method="">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="">
    </div>
    <div>    
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You cannot download file with HTML after form submit. You need backend solution PHP/Node.js to send the file to the browser.

Comment: You have the server side script that processes the form request output image data with an appropriate content-type header. How you do that depends on the server side programming language (Perl/PSGI, JavaScript/Node, PHP/mod_php, Java/Servelets, C#/ASP.NET, etc) you are using.

Comment: Please,anyone post php code for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have two approaches:

- From your server side, return a direct link to your file placed on the server (e.g: [this image](https://www.eatforhealth.gov.au/sites/default/files/images/the_guidelines/fruit_selection_155265101_web.jpg)). Be careful with this option.
- You load and process the image on your server, wrap and send it on the response via HTTP. (very useful if you have to send a pre-processed file like an auto generated PDF or XLS)

Both options have a lot of information and examples around the internet, just google it.